# Queue per User - Appengine Java - Design Advice

Tags: java, google-app-engine, queue

I am using AppEngine (Java) for our project.

We use queues (which run on backends) for time consuming tasks. However, some of the users have complained that their task doesn't run immediately and sometimes it even takes more than an hour or two before other tasks scheduled are cleared away.

Is there a possibility of smart scheduling where the users have their own queue and instead of round-robin, queues are executed user wise?

There is an ETA flag (in future) - I can check and put some repetitive tasks in queues for the same user in the future but if there are no queues, the tasks would be unnecessarily delayed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your user, a few ways I can think of:
If the user size is small (<10), you can simply assign each user a queue.
But usually, user size will be much larger, in this case, you can set up some code to perform throttle function. 
Basically, you define a rate which you allow each user's task to be executed in a given duration, e.g. each user is only allowed to be executed 3 task in 10 minute. When you grab the first task from the queue, check the counter (which you store in db) if it is less than 3, then execute the task and at the same time add the counter by 1. Or if the counter is already great than 3, throw it back to the end of the queue, or put it into another queue which has a lower priority (which again you can use code to control).
I believe there are other ways around, the best solution will based on many factors such as your tasks size, execution time, etc.

Comment: The answer is very generic and not pertinent to appengine.

Comment: @cloudpre Isn't it a good when a generic solution can solve your specific question? Anyway, this is how we implement our queues using AppEngine on Java which works great.

Comment: this route will force the tasks to execute only at 3 per min   though the queue is empty. It will be under limited.